How can I use threading and multiprocessing in python to allow functions to run constantly despite them taking different times?
I have a two functions that need to run constantly, but due to the fact they affect real world objects, there are certain constraints. I can't run the functions faster or slower or else the display begins to look choppy or the stepper tries to damage parts or itself.
import concurrent.futures as cf
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading as th
from gpiozero import OutputDevice as Opin
from time import sleep

stepdir = Opin(20)
steppul = Opin(21)

# This function is so fast, it is hard to measure the time it takes
def read():
"""
This function reads a series of sensors through GPIO and accessory boards.
"""
    val1 = measured_value1
    val2 = measured_value2
    ...
    output = (val1, val2, ...)
    return output

# This function rarely takes more than a thousandth of a second
def display(parseme):
"""
This function takes a series of values and parses them so they can be displayed on the correct gauge.
"""
    val1 = parseme[0]
    val2 = parseme[1]
    ...
    # These are functions imported from another file of mine
    gauge_pos1(val1)
    sleep(0.0001)
    gauge_pos2(val2)
    sleep(0.0001)
    ...

# This function takes up to a hundredth of a second. Fast in its own right, but a hundredth
# is an eternity to a display that works in a few ten-thousandths
def adjust_stepper(pos, delta):
"""
This function is fed a stepper position value and a delta value that determines if the
stepper needs to be moved and in what direction it needs to move.
"""
    if delta > 0.25:
        stepdir.on()
        steppul.on()
        sleep(0.005)
        steppul.off()
        sleep(0.005)
        pos += 1
    elif delta < 0.25:
        stepdir.off()
        steppul.on()
        sleep(0.005)
        steppul.off()
        sleep(0.005)
        pos -= 1
    return pos

while True:
    # First, I must measure
    measures = read()

    # Next, I must display
    display(measures)

    #Finally, I must adjust the stepper
    adjust_stepper(pos, delta)


I need to be constantly measuring inputs and displaying certain inputs, regardless of whether or not the adjust_stepper function is currently running the stepper. Right now, the measurements do run constantly, but the display stops because I can't restart the display function to run with the new inputs until the stepper is done moving and that function finishes.
I still haven't figured out what mix of concurrent.futures, threading, and multiprocessing will give the desired result. Should I be adding, removing, or reorganizing steps in this process?
So far, I've tried adding threading and multiprocessing, but the use of join() to make sure I don't try and give conflicting commands to the gauges or stepper leads me to the same problem. Now the functions can run at the same time, but I still can't update the display until the stepper is done moving due to join().

Do you read the delta value from the field? Is it an input measurement from the real position?

Delta is determined by pressure in this case, and the stepper position will directly affect whether pressure increases or decreases. I cannot use the position on its own for this as there are a number of other outside variables that can change the pressure. The delta is the difference between measured pressure and ideal pressure. I use whether delta is positive or negative to determine the direction the stepper should rotate in. The 0.25 is just an allowance.

I might have interpreted the question wrong

It's really not very clear what you are trying to do, nor what the constraints are. Also, you should only run join() at the very end of your application, not repeatedly. Normally, you do a thread.start() at the beginning of your app and then do a thread.join() several hours/minutes later when the app is ending.

Maybe start a thread that continually reads the sensors and adjusts the stepper and keeps running in a loop doing that until the app stops. Then run the display from the main thread which proceeds in parallel.

I was thinking that you may benefit from implementing a simple industrial PLC-like execution loop with clear actions: read input -> execute logic -> set outputs. In your case, the set outputs should send the delta value to the stepper. The stepper controller shoud be in a separate thread or an "output drivers subprocess".

Also, you should change those calls to sleep() to asyncio.sleep().

Nice, I did not know most of this. Let me try the code and I will come back with whether or not it worked
